# Raspbian 8 upgrade to Raspbian 9

Tags: raspbian

What were the specific changes in the communications or network settings between Raspbian 8 versus Raspbian 9?

Comment: Could you describe the specific problem that you have, or at least what you want to achieve and why do you think that changes in network settings would prevent you from achieving what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian is based on Debian so a first look about changes from **Debian 8** to **Debian 9** you should have at [What's new in Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html). For specific upgrades about **Raspbian** look at [Raspbian release notes](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt).

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a specific networking issue it's better if you add a bit of context to help us with some context.

Off the top of my head only:

1. Added the *predictable interface names* option (configurable in raspi-config, disabled by default in some cases, e.g. dist_upgrade)
2. Quite a lot of new networking chip drivers

If you updated to 9 and your network/wifi stopped working you should verify if (1) is disabled with `ifconfig` (your interfaces will have weird new names).

If you are using an old raspbian8 SD in a newer Raspberry, you have updated to 9 but the network doesn't work, your problem is (2), you'll have to grab the missing interface firmware descriptors manually form raspbian's github.

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated you should use `ip` instead.